# nullpointerexception after return entity from empty column

Tags: spring-boot, api, rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm working on app in Spring Boot. I want to get object from data base but first time that object is empty. I did that because i want to restrict asking DB for only once per day. But when i return empy optiona(i try that solution but doesn't work) or null and provide if statement which should "catch" it, i got null pointer exception. Someone know how to resolve it ?

```java
    public Statistics createSaveAndReturnStatistics() {
        User loggedUser = authService.getLoggedUser();
        Statistics statistics = statisticsRepository.findFirstByUserIdOrderByIdDesc(loggedUser.getId());
        ZonedDateTime creationDate = statistics.getCreationDate();

        if (statistics == null || todayWasNotSavedStatistics(creationDate) ) {
           //SOME CODE 
           return statisticsRepository.save(new Statistics());

        }
        return statistics;
    }

    private boolean todayWasNotSavedStatistics(ZonedDateTime creationDate) {
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

        return creationDate.getDayOfYear() != now.getDayOfYear() &&
                creationDate.getDayOfYear() <= now.getDayOfYear();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `statistics.getCreationDate()` before null checking in if statatement.
Probably that's why you are getting Nullpointerexception.

You can send `statistics.getCreationDate()` directly in `todayWasNotSavedStatistics()` method in if statement this way

```
if (statistics == null || todayWasNotSavedStatistics(statistics.getCreationDate())) {
    //SOME CODE 
   return statisticsRepository.save(new Statistics());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this. There were two problems. Solutions is really simple, I have forgotten add no args contructor to Entity. Second was as Eklavya said calling statistics.getCreationDate() before checking null.